# Secure Connection Failed on LTE Connection

Tags: internet, mobile-broadband

I have a problem with a Lenovo Thinkpad 8 tablet running Windows 10 Pro. After resetting from the Recovery menu, a problem with the LTE connection occurred. Although the Connected status appears, **any web page (https and http)** I try to open gives me the error: Secure Connection Failed. The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. 
I have tried to use the tablet as HotSpot and receive the same error message on client computer. I mention that there is LTE connectivity, I can ping IP addresses and DNS addresses.
The tablet works perfectly when connected via WiFi. The date and time are correctly configured.
I tried with a SIM card from another operator, but the same thing happened.
All drivers are UpToDate. 
 
**For a few minutes, the connection switched from 4G to 3G and everything worked perfectly. Both SIM cards are working on another devices.** 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should check the login credentials (username and password) and also the APN, it may be that after the restore are not configured correctly. Open the browser and type in the gateway address.

Comment: Connection is established, I can ping any addresses. Using Microsoft Edge I get a TLS Error Message. If I try to connect to a another computer I get the error when is trying to establish secure connection.

Comment: In Romania, 3G and 4G settings (username, password, apn) are the same. 3G is working fine, when is switching to 4G is not working.

Comment: No, it's not possible. the APN 3G is different from the 4G APN. Otherwise, the problem would concern the operator and not your device.

Comment: I had the same problem, so I called the operator and they gave me the correct APN. Username and password were the same.